# Embed Google Calendar with Colors for Events on Squarespace

Tags: google-calendar-api, squarespace

I have embedded a Google Calendar on my Squarespace website using a code block with the following code:

```
<div class="responsive-iframe-container big-container">
<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed? 
src=kirkstudmin%40gmail.com&ctz=America%2FChicago" style="border: 0" 
width="1500" height="1000" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

However, the calendar is not showing the events in their various colors like shown on Google Calendar. see here: http://www.thekirk.org/studentministry2#new-page-31

[Image of Google Calendar with colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWDGA.png)

Is there a way to add the colors to the coding?

Answer (score 0):

By using the [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) method, you will be able to set the color of each event. There is an optional property `colorId` that could be set to achieve this. In relation to that, try to visit the [colors endpoint](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/colors) to check on format for setting background and foreground colors.

Sample color response when calling [Colors: get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/colors/get) method is successful:

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#colors",
  "updated": datetime,
  "calendar": {
    (key): {
      "background": string,
      "foreground": string
    }
  },
  "event": {
    (key): {
      "background": string,
      "foreground": string
    }
  }
}
```